# Multiple sql joins same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this query:

`SELECT b.id, b.date, members.username, b.type, b.amount, FROM b LEFT JOIN members ON b.user_id = members.id WHERE a.something = 1`

Now I want to select another `members.username`, but now I want it to be by the `b.other_user_id`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the members table with a different alias on the required condition and select the required column from that table.

```
SELECT b.id, b.date, m1.username, b.type, b.amount, m2.username
FROM b 
LEFT JOIN members m1 ON b.user_id = m1.id AND a.something = 1
LEFT JOIN members m2 ON b.other_user_id = m2.id
```

Comment: shouldn't it be: .. JOIN members AS m1 ON ...?